# Eigenfunction corresponding to an eigenvalue = $0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Q) Is it true that for a stochastic matrix (row sums = $1$), if a particular eigenvalue = $0$, then the corresponding eigenfunction $\equiv 0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eigenfunctions are never zero. An eigenvalue is a value $\lambda$ such that there exists a nonzero[!] vector $v$, such that 
$$Av=\lambda v$$
We want the vector $v$ to be nonzero, since the zero vector fulfills this equation for every $\lambda$. So it is not a good definition for an eigenvalue.
This definition also implies 
$$0=Av-\lambda v=(A-\lambda \text{id})v $$
thus the matrix $(A-\lambda \text{id})$ does not have full rank. Or in other words, look for lambda such that 
$$\det(A-\lambda \text{id})=0.$$

Now if this is the case for $\lambda=0$, then it implies that there is a nonzero[!] vector which fulfills the initial condition. And such a vector is called an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Also note that if $v$ is an eigenvector, then $2v$ is also an eigenvector for the same eigenvalue $\lambda$. More generally the set of eigenvectors for an eigenvalue (+ the zero vector) is a vectorspace. So if you would allow $v=0$ as an eigenvector, then you would have lot's of eigenvalues where the eigenspace has dimension zero. So you exclude this case.

Remark: I am using eigenvectors and eigenfunctions interchangeably, since functions are really just vectors of the vectorspace of functions.

Comment: Still, if there are non-zero vectors with eigenvalue $\lambda$ (zero or not), we do want the $\lambda$-eigenspace to include $0$, so that it's a subspace. That is, there's some unavoidable issue about whether the $0$-vector is or isn't a $\lambda$-eigenvalue... but this should not usually be the genuine issue.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, an eigenfunction is not identically zero, so no, not true, but false.